# Pass Function Pointer as Parameter where the function pointer's parameter is a child of the function's function pointer parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, function-parameter

I am very sorry for the potentially complicated, and confusing, title, but before trying to destroy the English language, I will just put what I am looking at in C++ code.

```
//The parent struct
struct Parameters
{ 
};
//the derived struct
struct ParametersDerived : public Paramters
{
     //Paramters
     int paramData;

     //return values
     int retData;
};

//the function i am passing the function pointer to
void Function(void(*FunctionPointer)(Parameters*));

//the function pointer i am passing to the function
void FunctionToPass(ParametersDerived* param)
{
//TODO: do stuff here
}

//Call the function with the function pointer
Function(FunctionToPass);
```

This is seriously confusing me, because I need to pass a function pointer to a function, but the parameters of said function pointer will vary.  I will be passing multiple different function pointers to this function, because it keeps a list of the function pointers.  Each of the function pointers has a unique id that is used to call the function, then the parameters is passed through that e.g. `void CallFunction(unsigned int FuncId, Parameters* param)`.  This is not the exact system, because that is proprietary, but it utilizes the same concept.  For all intensive purposes, the functions are ALL global.  Also, I would like to keep the system I am trying to create, but If i had something similar that was better, I would be glad to adopt it.

Comment: Why can't you change your function type to `void FunctionToPass(Parameters *)`?

Comment: I need to make sure that the FunctionToPass can ONLY take ParamtersDerived* because in the situation that I have, it is possible (while not likely) that it could get the wrong parameter.  It is better for it not to be called than for it to have bad memory that it works with

Comment: If it only takes `ParametersDerived*` then how would it make sense to pass it to something that could give you a `Parameters*`?

Comment: It can only take parametersDerived, but since i am storing a list of function pointers, it needs a common base to store it as

Comment: @Stefan: I'm pretty sure I've seen a question with that exact title before.  Or was the original one returning a pointer to a function that accepts a pointer to a function returning a pointer?  I can't remember :(

Comment: If it can only take ParametersDerived then it can't be safely stored in that list.

Comment: Please revert your last edit as well.

Comment: Can you please clarify how the function decides which arguments to pass to which function pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the functions to take a `void *` as argument.

```
//the function i am passing the function pointer to
void Function(void(*FunctionPointer)(void*));

//the function pointer i am passing to the function
void FunctionToPass(void* voidparam)
{
    ParametersDerived* param = (ParametersDerived*)voidparam;
    //TODO: do stuff here
}
```

Of course, it is **very** important that the right parameters are passed to the functions, because the compiler cannot check the type safety anymore.

**ANSWER DOWN HERE:**

**I have just noticed your comment**, to ensure type safety (assuming you really want to keep the 'function pointer' approach), you could add a member to the base parameter structure, for example `int ParameterType`, and check that in the called functions.

```
//The parent struct
struct Parameters
{ 
    int ParameterType;
};
```

Comment: @MattMcNabb Ok, but isn't the `void *` version better then, because the compiler will produce an error if there is not exactly one pointer passed?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Just to make sure there is no misunderstanding: I don't cast the function pointer to `void*`, just the argument.

Comment: @MattMcNabb The function pointer is `void(*FunctionPointer)(void*)`, and `FunctionToPass(void* voidparam)` is a function which's address can be passed to `Function(void(*FunctionPointer)(void*))`.

Comment: Can you update your post to show how `Function` should be called?

Comment: @MattMcNabb `Function(&FunctionToPass);`

Comment: That's not updating your post. Also, where is the voidparam in that?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, I know, but OP edited my answer and I felt it would be rude to edit that away. The voidparam will be used together with `FunctionPointer`. `Function` will create `Parameters param;` and call `FunctionPointer(&param);`. Then `FunctionToPass` will cast `voidparam` back to `Parameters*`.

Comment: It's not rude to edit your own answer.  Maybe you could include those details in the answer for clarification.  I'll delete my comments as I misunderstood what your code was trying to do.  (I wouldn't say I understand it now -- for example if Function always creates Parameters then when not just make the function pointer take `Parameters*` instead of `void *`?) but OP understands what you meant and that's all that counts

Comment: @MattMcNabb You are right, as the question is now, the function could take `Parameters*`. But first, `ParametersDervied` was not derived from `Parameters`, that was edited in later.

Comment: Even if it wasn't derived then casting to a function pointer type taking a `void *` parameter makes no difference over casting to the actual type required

Comment: @MattMcNabb the problem was that `Function` should take function pointers to functions taking `Parameters*` or `ParametersDerived*`.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion of casting both types to `void (*)(void*)` is no improvement on casting both types to `void (*)(Parameters*)` (omitting casts where not necessary of course)

Comment: @MattMcNabb if `ParametersDerived` is not derived from `Parameters`, you have to cast it first to `Parameters*` and then back to `ParametersDerived*`, while you wouldn't have to cast it to `void*`, just back, so you save one cast with the `void*` version.

Comment: But you have an extra cast in having to cast the function pointer to the type that takes `void *`

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, but somehow I felt it would be better to have a void*, because it reminds you that it has to be cast to something useful. But maybe a `Parameters*` would really have been better even when the two types were not related, I don't know.

Comment: could you please update your post with the example usage (and perhaps also to reflect the updated question)